# Compute engine | Failed to start LSB: data collector for treasure Data

Tags: php, wordpress, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've set up a new virtual machine with wordpress on google's compute engine.
Now I'm facing the following problem:

Wordpress has released a new update (5.4) and I want update it. To do that, I need to do an upgrade of the vm because the installation of the new wordpress version fails and can't even start.

So now my thoughts on solving this problem were, maybe I need to update the php version or the whole vm.

I tried to do it but now i'm getting the following error: Failed to start LSB: data colector for treasure Data.

This is what i've got when I used the command `sudo apt upgrade -y`

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up google-fluentd (1.6.33-1) ...
Conffile /etc/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.conf has been modified. Remain untouched.
Job for google-fluentd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status google-fluentd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript google-fluentd, action "start" failed.
● google-fluentd.service - LSB: data collector for Treasure Data
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/google-fluentd; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-04-19 20:15:44 UTC; 20ms ago
    Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Process: 20187 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/google-fluentd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Apr 19 20:15:44 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: Starting LSB: data collector for Treasure Data...
Apr 19 20:15:44 agentur-m-wp-vm google-fluentd[20187]: Starting google-fluentd 1.6.33: Disabled via metadata …ing).
Apr 19 20:15:44 agentur-m-wp-vm google-fluentd[20187]: google-fluentd ... failed!
Apr 19 20:15:44 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: google-fluentd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 19 20:15:44 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: data collector for Treasure Data.
Apr 19 20:15:44 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: google-fluentd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 19 20:15:44 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: google-fluentd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package google-fluentd (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
google-fluentd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm really not experienced with SSH so I would be the happiest human on earth if you could help me with this issue.

Thank you so much.

Kind regards
Vazanity.

EDIT:
If this helps you I used this command to get a detailed error message:
`journalctl -xe`

And this is what I got:

```
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 13min 21.259584s random time.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: certbot.timer: Adding 10h 18min 6.712498s random time.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
-- Subject: Unit apt-daily.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit apt-daily.service has begun starting up.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: Reloading.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: certbot.timer: Adding 2h 11min 1.812555s random time.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: certbot.timer: Adding 5h 3min 3.480078s random time.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 55min 49.753301s random time.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
-- Subject: Unit apt-daily.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit apt-daily.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 3h 27min 38.579330s random time.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 7h 2min 37.043471s random time.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: Starting LSB: data collector for Treasure Data...
-- Subject: Unit google-fluentd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit google-fluentd.service has begun starting up.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm google-fluentd[20542]: Starting google-fluentd 1.6.33: Disabled via metadata ... (w
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm google-fluentd[20542]: google-fluentd ... failed!
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: google-fluentd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: data collector for Treasure Data.
-- Subject: Unit google-fluentd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit google-fluentd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: google-fluentd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: google-fluentd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm sudo[20460]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
lines 1308-1349/1349 (END)
```

UPDATE:
Now when I do `sudo apt update`

I get the following output:

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease        
Hit:4 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian stretch InRelease            
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease           
Hit:6 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-wheezy InRelease
Hit:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release                       
Hit:8 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-monitoring-stretch InRelease
Hit:9 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-stretch InRelease
Hit:10 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-stretch-stable InRelease
Hit:11 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-stretch InRelease
Get:12 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch InRelease [6,760 B]
Fetched 6,760 B in 1s (6,311 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
13 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

`sudo apt upgrade` went well, all packages have been installed/updated.

Now I tried to update wordpress again via backend and it still says "download failed" , "something went wrong".

Nothing more.

**NEW UPDATE**

I am running now `sudo apt list --upgradable`
and get the following output: Listing Done

(It seems like everything has been upgraded)

To be sure I'm running now the next command `sudo apt upgrade -y`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  sgml-base xml-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Well. My assumption was right.. but still can't update wordpress in the backend..

What am I doing wrong... :(

Answer (score 4):

I encountered same problem. You should stop and uninstall google-fluentd with this command:

sudo service google-fluentd stop && sudo apt-get remove google-fluentd google-fluentd-catch-all-config

Answer (score 3):

You have an issue with the [logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent) `google-fluentd`:

```
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm systemd[1]: Starting LSB: data collector for Treasure Data
```

and the reason for it you can see in the logs as well:

```
Apr 19 20:29:23 agentur-m-wp-vm google-fluentd[20542]: Starting google-fluentd 1.6.33: Disabled via metadata
```

Have a look at the documentation [Troubleshooting the Agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/troubleshooting):

> If the restart fails, **and the log output shows "Disabled via
>   metadata", you are likely running an image from Google Cloud
>   Marketplace, where the Logging agent is disabled by default**. This is
>   controlled by the `google-logging-enable` instance metadata key (with
>   the value 0).

**To solve your issue**:

- restart the agent:

  ```
  sudo service google-fluentd status
  ```

  and check logs if you have the same error `Disabled via metadata`
- re-enable the agent by following [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/troubleshooting#checklist):

  > To re-enable the agent, either remove that key or set
  >   the value to 1 (see [Setting instance
  >   metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#updatinginstancemetadata)).
- restart and check status of the agent again:

  ```
  sudo service google-fluentd restart
  sudo service google-fluentd status
  ```

  if you see no errors you can run `sudo apt upgrade -y` again.

Do not forget to create a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots)/backup to protect your data before any changes.

**EDIT** Have a look at the documentation  [Updating WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/) and if nothing helps try  [Manual Update](https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update).

Comment: thanks for your help! It seems like I have no errors anymore. I just did the upgrade but something seems odd? It says that 1 was not fully installed. Why is that?

Comment: it seems like it worked but still can't update wordpress. The VM says there are 13 packe updates available. Is there a way to update these all together?

Comment: Please update your question with output of the commands `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Also please share your steps to upgrade WordPress and the error message.

Comment: Hi Serhii, I did your steps and updated my question above.

Comment: Have a look at the message '13 packages can be upgraded', at first you should run 'sudo apt list --upgradable' and after that run 'sudo apt upgrade -y'. Please update your question with full output of these commands.

Comment: Okay, you've updated all the software on your VM. I've updated my answer with extra instructions related directly to WordPress.

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade WordPress manually you can open a ticket at WordPress forums like https://wordpress.org/support/forums/ and/or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ in addition to this because your issue with WordPress could be specific.

Comment: Hi Serhii, the problem is, I dont have access to FTP because its a google VM.. aww god I wish the problem could be solved but it seems like i need to do everyting new :(

Comment: You can open any ports towards VM instance in Google Cloud by following documentation [Creating firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules). In addition, have a look at this article [10 steps to setup FTP server on Google Compute Engine](https://rogulski.it/blog/ftp-on-google-compute-enigne/). What do you mean by saying "a google VM"?